# JAVA: java.nio.Files move command not working for shared NAS location

Tags: java, unix, java.nio.file

I'm trying to move a file from a local directory to a shared NAS directory. But I'm getting "*java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException*" exception. Can anyone let me know whether there is another way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/localdir/tempfile.zip_2021-11-12-12_19_27_0327");
Path path2 = Paths.get("/sharednas/finish/tempfile.zip_2021-11-12-12_19_27_0327");
Files.move(path1, path2, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

**Exception:**

```
Unable to move zip file back to target directory. Error details {}
java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException: /localdir/tempfile.zip_2021-11-12-12_19_27_0327 -> /sharednas/finish/tempfile.zip_2021-11-12-12_19_27_0327: Invalid cross-device link
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:394) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.util.FileUtils.moveFiles(FileUtils.java:106) [classes!/:?]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.service.MyMain.moveZipFileWithTimeStamp(MyMain.java:298) [classes!/:?]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.Main.moveZipFileToDoneDir(Main.java:148) [classes!/:?]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.Main.processMyFile(Main.java:131) [classes!/:?]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.Main.initialize(Main.java:87) [classes!/:?]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.Main.run(Main.java:78) [classes!/:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringMain.callRunner(SpringMain.java:804) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringMain.callRunners(SpringMain.java:788) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringMain.run(SpringMain.java:333) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringMain.run(SpringMain.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringMain.run(SpringMain.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at com.petproject.movingFiles.Main.main(Main.java:68) [classes!/:?]
```

Comment: If atomic move is not supported, then why not try this without `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE`?

Comment: It's working after removing StandardCopyOption. But is there any explanation why ATOMIC MOVE is throwing the exception?

Comment: [As documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), that method will throw an `AtomicMoveNotSupportedException` "_if the options array contains the ATOMIC_MOVE option but the file cannot be moved as an atomic file system operation_".

Comment: Thanks for the information @Slaw